# How do I combine FOR XML PATH ROOT RAW ELEMENT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

Below is output I need to get :

```
    <myRoot xmlns="myNamespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.xxx.zzz/XMLSchema-instance">
<myPath>
    <GrpHdr>
        <MsgId>decimal</MsgId>
    </GrpHdr>
    <Stmt>
        <Bal>
            <Tp>
                <Cd>string</Cd>
            </Tp>
        </Bal>
    </Stmt>
    <Amt Ccy="string">decimal</Amt>
</myPath>
```

The problem (my problem) is :

```
    <Amt Ccy="string">decimal</Amt>
```

Using inner query and FOR XML RAW I can only get :

```
    <Amt Ccy="string" />
```

I still need to place decimal value which is actually Amt value and close it with

```
    </Amt>
```

Is it doable ? Cheers.

```
    DECLARE @DayID datetime 
    DECLARE @Account numeric(26) 
    SELECT
    S.Statement         AS "GrpHdr/MsgId",
    'OBCD'              AS "Stmt/Bal/Tp/Cd",
    (SELECT [dbo].[GetAccountCurrency](@DayID , @Account )      AS "Ccy"
    FROM [output].[statements] AS S
    WHERE DayID = @DayID AND Account = @Account AND TYPE = 'D'
    FOR XML RAW ('Amt') , TYPE)
    FROM [output].[statements] AS S
    JOIN [dbo].[TAP00201]      AS T
    ON  DayID = date    AND 
    CAST (RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(26), Account ), 10) AS NUMERIC) = DMACCT
    WHERE DayID = @DayID AND Account = @Account AND TYPE = 'D'
    FOR XML PATH ('BkToCstmrStmtV01'), ROOT ('Document')
```

Nothing as to Amt value, as yet, since I have no foggiest idea how to close it with  Amount value is supposed to be taken either from record table or parsed as variable.

Comment: Please add your current query so it's easier to help

Comment: Thank you Sami Kuhmonen for your reply. Query added

Answer (score 0):

It's usually much easier to use [`for xml path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx):

```
...
select
    dbo.GetAccountCurrency(@DayID , @Account) as "@Ccy",
    'decimal' as "data()"
from [output].[statements] as S
where S.DayID = @DayID and S.Account = @Account and S.[Type] = 'D'
for xml path('Amt'), type
...
```